# Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem: rank $\le$ k or rank = k

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, svd

The Eckart–Young–Mirsky theorem is stated sometimes with rank $\le$ k and sometimes with rank = k. Why?

More specifically, why the following two optimization problems are equivalent:

Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$, and a natural number $k < $ rank(A).

1. $\min_{B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}, rank(B) \color{red}\le k}||A-B||^2_F$
2. $\min_{B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}, rank(B) \color{red}= k}||A-B||^2_F$

Comment: Did you mean $k < \mathrm{rank}(A)$? If you allow $B$ to have the same rank as $A$, obviously the minimum is $ \| A - A \|_F = 0$.

Comment: You are right, but I don't see how this would be a problem.

Comment: It isn't a problem, but it would make the equivalence trivial. For $k < \mathrm{rank}(A)$, the equivalence arises by characterizing the optimal solution, which is the projection of $A$ to its $k$ largest singular values.

Comment: Answer: [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/366634/eckart-young-mirsky-theorem-rank-%E2%89%A4k-or-rank-k/367111#367111)